# What is this side menu called that can be found in many multi-touch apps, and where does it originate from?

Tags: gui-design, menu, terminology, taxonomy, history

It can be found for example in the YouTube and Facebook app.
[image]
[image]

Comment: As far as I've heard the hamburguer menu (at least on mobile apps) was introduced by Loren Britcher on a twitter client or app of his own, as the "drag downward to update" gesture, and then twitter bought his Idea for a 1-digit-million(s) xD. Read about that a while ago so I'm not sure about how right am I. do some research on it guys xD

Comment: I believe it is important in this type of discussion to include the principle of "Out of sight, out of mind" which has been a major problem with these type of interfaces: http://thenextweb.com/dd/2014/04/08/ux-designers-side-drawer-navigation-costing-half-user-engagement/?utm_source=t.co&utm_content=UX%20designers:%20Side%20drawer%20navigation%20could%20be%20costing%20you%20half%20your%20user%20engagement&utm_campaign=share%20button&awesm=tnw.to_t3K1z&utm_medium=referral

Comment: @mcb I'm not sure what you're referring to. I'm just pointing out that when site/app features are hidden in a menu engagement drop. This is based on the article I linked.

Comment: @mcb It's not sad. I'm not saying off-canvas interactions don't work. I *am* saying that "out of sight, out of mind" needs to be *considered* when designing interfaces with that pattern.

Comment: It is called the Menu Navigation Icon, referred to as the Navicon.

Comment: @BigMac Do you have a source for that?

Comment: It's alternatively called the **Hotdog menu**

Answer (score 82, accepted):

I believe the going name for it is a **Hamburger Menu**, as a reference to the icon that's commonly used for it *([image: ux-hamburger-drawer-icon.333-tr.s20], similar to the Unicode character `≡ U+2261 Identical To`)*, and to the stacked nature of the items in the drawer. **Hamburger Drawer** and **Hamburger Sidebar** would also be recognizable terms to the UX community.

---

A bit of discussion on what I believe to be the proper usage of the term:

The menu itself is nothing new; sidebar menus with links to various parts of an app/site have been used this way since the early web (and probably elsewhere perhaps earlier still).  Also, buttons that toggle hidden content or optionally allow dragging to reveal content have also existed for much longer than touchscreen smartphones; the [drawer in older versions of QuickTime Player](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aBWww.jpg) and [OS X's color picker swatch drawer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6YKbR.png) are good examples of this.

This pattern is then best described as the combination of the drawer menu and reveal/hide button patterns in a manner where:

- The main content slides out of the way or remains visually underneath, revealing the drawer by button tap or drag,
- The drawer content is meta content intended for temporary access (navigation buttons, chat contact list, etc.),
- Tapping back on the partially-visible main content area closes the drawer,
- The activation button is always visible, and featured in the “navigation” header/footer immediately next to the side the drawer will appear on.

There exists (of course) variants that bend the above guidelines— some implementations may only allow tapping (not dragging) the button, or the tap-to-restore-main-content functionality might be omitted when presenting the same app on a larger-screen device, or the drawer might be oddly used for something non-clickable.  Because of this, the above points describe the idealized and common form of the pattern which has quickly grown into popularity and widespread usage.

I assume that one of the reasons this pattern hadn't popped up in this form earlier (and why it deserves distinction from other patterns) is that prior to touchscreen smartphones, UI design was not nearly as often constrained to fixed-size fullscreen.  Because of this new constraint, the concept of the main content temporarily sliding off the screen and the modal nature of the menu were deemed necessary, and out of that grew the benefits of hiding unnecessary visual clutter and providing a menu that can be any length without redesign.  It probably also helped that Apple's UIToolbar approach of a “More” button only half-solved a brewing problem.

---

The first place I remember seeing a sidebar drawer of this kind was in the now-defunct Tweetie app for iPad. webOS has also had drawers like this for quite a while, but I don't think either employed the “hamburger” button nor fixed-width drawer size. I have no definite answer for you on this one, but [the](https://github.com/mystcolor/JTRevealSidebarDemo). [number](https://github.com/JPluto/DDMenuController). [of](https://github.com/pkluz/PKRevealController). [open](https://github.com/Inferis/ViewDeck). [source](https://github.com/gotosleep/JASidePanels). [libraries](https://github.com/inonb/SlideMenuController2). [for](https://github.com/meiwin/MWFSlideNavigationViewController). [making](https://github.com/edgecase/ECSlidingViewController). [these](https://github.com/jeremieweldin/JWSlideMenu). [kind](https://github.com/BenHall/ios_facebook_style_navigation). [of](https://github.com/iridia/IRSlidingSplitViewController). [sidebar](https://github.com/ipup/PPRevealSideViewController). [menus](https://github.com/wess/WCStackNavigationController). on GitHub seem to all point to the Facebook iOS app as you've mentioned, and to Path.

I suppose **Facebook/Path-Style Sidebar/Menu/Drawer** could be considered a going term for it, though I predict the references to company names would antiquate that before too long.

Comment: I can't say I've ever heard of it referred to as a hamburger menu before. Where have you seen this before?

Comment: If it is indeed called the hamburger drawer.. I think this is my new favorite name for a UX device.

Comment: @JonW: I picked up on the name from a short article at The Industry (http://theindustry.cc/2013/01/07/13-design-trends-for-2013/) by a Gannon **Burgett** _(imagine that)_. Though he references good ol' Marco Arment, and Marco has used the term before (https://twitter.com/marcoarment/status/274003293473218561 or http://cl.ly/M9kD/), so maybe he coined it.

Comment: Interestingly, Google Chrome calls that button a [hotdog](http://googlechromereleases.blogspot.com/2012/11/dev-and-beta-update-for-chrome-os.html) .

Comment: @Brian: **The Meat-Or-Meatlike-Product-In-A-Bun Menu**

Comment: @slipp-d-thompson I think Mark Kawano just beat Marco to it in this [tweet](https://twitter.com/markkawano/status/256848377260679168). Mark talks about it in this [Iterate](http://www.imore.com/iterate-44-mark-kawano-and-evangelizing-experience) podcast.

Comment: Technically, the "hamburger" terminology refers to the specific three bars icon that resembles a big mac, not necessarily the sidebar drawer execution of the menu itself. As you can see from the OPs screenshots, the sidebar drawer implementation has been successfully executed without the hamberger icon, using instead things like an arrow, etc.

Comment: @JoelGlovier I think there's a number of ways to look at it.  There's the icon itself, which strangely is horizontal lines not vertical lines like the resize/gripper buttons of yore.  Then there's the stacked nature of the menu, like a super-tall burger.  And then there's the layered feel of the screen, like one is sliding off the top bun to reveal what's inside.  None of these concisely say “hamburger” or “hotdog”, but with the union of these interpretations (and perhaps others), the name seems to have stuck.

Comment: The inclusion of the menu as the default in Bootstrap really launched the feature.

Comment: I just have to say that I hate this name.  It should be drowned into non-memory with copious single-malt

Comment: @NewAlexandria If I ever chance upon a new UI concept to coin, I'm going to think of you and seriously consider naming it **The Single-Malt Menu/Button/Bar/Indicator/Widget/etc**.

Answer (score 24):

**Side panel** As mentioned [at appadvice](http://appadvice.com/appnn/2012/09/upset-that-youtube-was-no-more-in-ios-6-fear-not-youtube-arrives-in-the-app-store)

> The app features a pretty slick interface, and uses the side panel for navigation.

Comment: +1, I've only ever heard "side panel" and "side menu" before...

Comment: I would say that “side panel” and “side menu” refer a panel/menu on the side, not the whole concept of content sliding away with a tap or drag to reveal a side panel/menu.  That is to say — IMHO — **a side panel/menu** is a much more established and generalized UI concept, which is used as a part of this specific combination of elements that has come into vogue recently.  _So that would make AppAdvice not incorrect, just unspecific._

Answer (score 24):

The layout pattern itself (not the burger icon) is known as '**Off Canvas**'. Luke Wroblewski wrote about it in an article about [Multi-Device Layout Patterns](http://www.lukew.com/ff/entry.asp?1514).

> ...the **Off Canvas** pattern for multi-device layout takes advantage of
>   space off the screen to keep content or navigation hidden until either
>   a larger screen size allows it to be visible or a user takes action to
>   expose it. This pattern is showing up in a few separate mobile Web
>   site designs and native mobile applications.

It has been implemented in frameworks like [Zurb Foundation](http://zurb.com/playground/off-canvas-layouts).

> If you've used Facebook's iPhone app (or Path, or any number of apps
>   that now follow this convention) then you've seen an **off canvas** panel
>   in a native app. You hit a button and a panel slides in from the left
>   (or depending on how you look at it, the main panel slides out of the
>   way).

And covered in articles such as [Off The Beaten Canvas: Exploring The Potential Of The **Off-Canvas Pattern**](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2014/02/24/off-the-beaten-canvas-exploring-the-potential-of-the-off-canvas-pattern/) by Smashing Magazine:

> The **off-canvas** flyout menu has taken over as the primary navigation
>   pattern for mobile layouts — even some desktop layouts have jumped on
>   board. And for good reason: An **off-canvas menu** is a great way to
>   maintain context while giving the user a lot of additional
>   information.

Answer (score 22):

To expound on what @matt_d_rat wrote,

There's [a great write-up here](https://www.evernote.com/shard/s207/sh/022f2237-4b4f-4096-87f2-053acd228c2d/ede2672bc3f39a1b0232f84e01ca0a83) about this, but it was originally designed by [Norm Cox](http://www.coxhall.com/bio.html) for the Xerox Star workstation in 1981!  This icon is about as old as the concept of GUI itself!

To see it in action [check out this video](https://vimeo.com/61556918) and skip to around 21 minutes.

[image: Xerox Star Workstation - Hamburger Menu!]

Comment: This needs more upvotes since it's the actual answer for "where does it originate from".

Answer (score 13):

According to the [Android Developer site](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html) and [Google Design specification](https://www.google.com/design/spec/patterns/navigation-drawer.html) it's known as a **Navigation Drawer**.

Comment: That link is about implementing the drawer; from UX perspective this may be more interesting: [Navigation Drawer in Android design guide](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation-drawer.html)

Answer (score 8):

Out of a related discussion which started on [Quora](http://www.quora.com/User-Interfaces/Who-started-the-trend-of-using-the-hamburger-icon-%E2%98%B0-as-a-menu-button), Geoff Alday dug a little deeper into the origins of the icon itself and discovered that Norm Cox is the man credited with designing the icon for the Xerox Star personal workstation, which was introduced in 1981.

In an [e-mail conversation](https://www.evernote.com/shard/s207/sh/022f2237-4b4f-4096-87f2-053acd228c2d/ede2672bc3f39a1b0232f84e01ca0a83) between Cox and Alday, Cox reveals how the icon came about and the design constraints they were working under. While today the icon is lovingly referred to as the hamburger icon, Cox reveals Xerox's own inside joke for the icon;

> We used to tell potential users that the image was an "air vent" to keep the window cool.

Comment: Damn. I was right!

Answer (score 4):

**Side Navigation** is one proposed term, as stated here:
http://www.androiduipatterns.com/2012/06/emerging-ui-pattern-side-navigation.html

It's a worth-while reading, which explains why this bring innovation to the navigation mechanisms of apps.

It also lists other candidate terms:

- Fly-in app menu
- Slide out navigation
- Sliding navigation bar
- Slide menu

Answer (score 3):

I've heard both hamburger menu and **fly-out menu**. In my work environment in Austin, fly-out menu is the most commonly used term.

Answer (score 2):

This would be called a "Hamburger Menu."

Avid Media Composer (a professional video editing suite that hasn't changed it's UI for literally decades) has menus that have a similar icon that they call "hamburger menus." It's possible that this is the origin of the name.

Comment: Technically the "hamburger" terminology refers to a specific style of menu icon that resembles the hamburger in a bun, not necessarily to the sliding sidebar drawer implementation of the menu. In fact, even in the OPs screenshots there is actually no hamberger icon used.

Comment: Bottommost screenshot (YouTube on iPad).  It's there.