# How can I deal with many buttons in a scope bar?

Tags: gui-design, ios, design, scope

I am looking for a UI way to deal with more title buttons than one can put in a scope bar. All of the screenshot/examples I see only deal with 3 or 4 options. What if I have 10?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to redo your information architecture and put these extra top navigation elements in a hamburger menu (a drop-down illustrated by three horizontal lines).

Comment: Thank you Benny. Any links to a screenshot or something similar so I can more easily see what you mean?

Comment: @user39372 sure thing! http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/32877/what-is-this-side-menu-called-that-can-be-found-in-many-multi-touch-apps-and-wh