# Menu with a lot of menu items for iPad

Tags: navigation, menu, ipad

I'm working on the iPad app, and I need to show a menu with about 15 menu items. For the website I would simply create a menu with sub-menus, but for the mobile app it seems it is not the commonly used solution. Are there any common patterns to solve this problem? Are there any good apps that I can use as examples? I can only think about LinkedIn for iPad with a scrolling menu.

Comment: Is this menu taking up the entire screen, or is it one which is displayed alongside your main content?

Comment: The requirement is that menu should not be the full screen. But if you have good examples of the full screen menu for a tablet then we might reconsider this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A nice format for displaying a large volume of menu items is the "Hamburger Menu". There was a question on this a while ago, with some nice screenshots [which you can find here](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/32877/what-is-this-side-menu-called-that-can-be-found-in-many-multi-touch-apps-and-wh). As you can see it can be almost full screen (with a small sliver of main content as affordance on how to exit the menu) on a phone sized device, but doesn't need to take up the entire screen for tablets.

With 15 menu items, you also need to think *"Do I display them side by side, or do I hide them under categories?"*.

It's better to avoid any kind of scrolling in a menu, so you could just display categories in your menu, and have each category slide open [accordian style](http://cssmenumaker.com/blog/5-sexy-accordion-menu-designs).