# iOS: Alternatives to UITabBarController

Tags: navigation, ios, menu

I do have an iPhone and iPad native application that mainly consists in a login screen after which comes a UITabBarController with 5 options/parts.

My problem now is that I am about to include new sections and I wouldn't like to end with a "More" tab like here

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/O59gx.png].

I am seriously considering moving into a Slide schema like this:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1MT5R.png]

but I would like to explore other possibilities before making a decision.

Is there something else that I could consider?

**Update:** here is a good explanation about why the *hamburger menu* is not a good idea: http://blog.manbolo.com/2014/06/30/apple-on-hamburger-menus

Answer (score 1):

Hamburger Menu can be a good option. There is a discussion about is it a good thing or not:

[Hamburger Menu - is it a good thing?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/41712/hamburger-menu-is-it-a-good-thing)

You can find some alternatives suggested in that question.

Also you could have scrolling menu (like LinkedIn app for iPad) or accordion, or tap and hold menu. Some people complain that scrolling menu is not a good choice:

[Menu with a lot of menu items for iPad](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/56387/menu-with-a-lot-of-menu-items-for-ipad)

Or probably app can become more workflow oriented, which could reduce the number of items in the main menu:

http://blog.cloudfour.com/responsive-design-for-apps-part-2/

Answer (score 1):

Here are a couple of alternatives I could think of :

1. An alternate option you can look at is the **overflow menu option** as shown below

[image]

This would allow you to stack the additional content in an overlay which can be pulled up as needed and would not be the primary navigation but more like the secondary navigation.

Dropbox provides a whole list of options using this navigation method as shown below

[image]

2. Another **option you can look at is including the whole navigation inside the menu** option as shown below

[image]

While this is quite similar to the Facebook option you gave, t**his gives you flexibility in ensuring all the menu options are given equal weight age** as opposed to the facebook option where the items are the top will have a higher interaction as opposed to items right at the bottom.

Here are some [navigation patterns worth reading about](http://designmodo.com/navigation-patterns-mobile/) (do note some of them are specific to android and may not apply in your case)